# QNetworkReply has no data

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qwebview

I have a [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html) where I'm watching the network requests by connecting:

```
  QObject::connect(page()->networkAccessManager(),
                     SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this,
                     SLOT(networkLoaded(QNetworkReply*)));
```

then:

```
void browserControl::networkLoaded(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    const QUrl reqUrl = reply->request().url();
    qDebug() << "url = " << reqUrl;

    QByteArray array = reply->readAll();
    QString data = QString::fromUtf8(array.data(), array.size());
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).value<int>();

 qDebug() << "data = " << data;
    qDebug() << "http code = " << statusCode;
}
```

But data is always empty, not matter if `statusCode` is `200`. `browserControl` class is inheried from `QWebView` class.

Comment: Are you certain the incoming data is actually UTF-8? Also, have you wiresharked it to make sure there's actually data coming in?

Comment: Check reply->error() and errorString()

Comment: It's empty probably because page did read everything before you

Comment: Kamil is right, you’re interfering with the WebView’s reading of the replies. Only one receiver can “consume” the data, and the first signal receiver is most probably the WebView.

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Post it as answer so I can accept

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Why is the data "cleaned" after consumed? wouldn't be better to provide some pointer to the data to use in case like this?

Comment: @Jack: That’s how QNetworkReply works: You read the data as it arrives (or collect it in the end, but that’s your choice), and it won’t be stored in the reply afterwards. Imagine a download in the size of Gigabytes, you don’t really want that all in memory all at the same time.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I understand it now. Thanks for clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no data because `QWebPage` read all data before your slot is called

Comment: How can I prevent QWebPage from read that data from a certain URL? override `QWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest()` on target URL?